# How can I work with variables after a variables in perl

Tags: perl, variables

How can I work with variables after a variable in perl. I want a script with it I can format disk.

```
./myscript.perl -d sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4 -f
```

I want to repeat commands with every sdb and if there is `-f` I want to run some commands more for every sdb.

Comment: See [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) for more information about how to parse command line options in Perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a Perl program, any command-line arguments can be found in the array `@ARGV`.

You could parse the contents of that array for yourself, but it will almost certainly be easier to use one of Perl's many option-parsing modules. [Getopt::Std](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Std) and [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long), for example, are both part of a standard Perl installation.

Using Getopt::Long, you could write code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Getopt::Long;

my (@d, $f);

GetOptions(
  'd=s{1,}' => \@d,
  'f' => \$f,
);

say "d: @d";
say "f: ", ($f ? 'true' : 'false');
```

Putting this in a file called `myscript`, I get the following output:

```
$ ./myscript -d xxx yyy zzz
d: xxx yyy zzz
f: false
$ ./myscript -d xxx yyy zzz -f
d: xxx yyy zzz
f: true
$ ./myscript -d xxx -f
d: xxx
f: true
```